# Make JS type a clickable link

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, clickable

I want to create a simple browser game for my brother's birthday and I'm stuck. This is a code I found at [https://codepen.io/TehMerow/pen/RGQOEK]. After a correct input, I want JS to type a clickable link for the next level. How do I do that? Another possibility is to make JS redirect to a new page if a correct input is written down, but it seems more complicated to me.
Please, tell me exactly where to insert the missing lines because otherwise I won't know how to implement it. TIA!

```
var area = document.querySelector('.box-text');
var input = document.querySelector('.cmd-text');
var box = document.querySelector('.box');
var title = `Welcome, to Shady Brook Hills`
var start = `

placeholder`;

var help = `
the commands are:
help: the current command.
stand up: stand up from the current position`

var credits = `
story writer: TehMerow;
coding: TehMerow;
`
function typeWrite(text, n, delay, area){
    if(n < (text.length)){
      area.innerText += text[n];
      n++
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
      typeWrite(text, n, delay, area);
    }, delay)
}
typeWrite(title, 0, 0, area);
setTimeout(function(){
  typeWrite(start, 0, 0, area);
}, 3000)

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
  e.preventDefault;

  if(e.which === 13 ){

    switch(input.value){
      case 'help':
        typeWrite('\n' + input.value + help, 0, 50, area);
        break;
      case '':
        input.value = '';
        break;
      case 'credits':
        typeWrite(credits, 0, 25, area);
        break;
      default:
        typeWrite('\n' + "I don't know how to " + input.value, 0, 50, area);
        break;
    }

    //ensure that bottom line is 
    //alays in view
    box.scrollTop += 100;
    //empty input
    input.value = ''
  }

}, false)
```

Comment: Looks pretty similar to https://github.com/thepix/questjs. You might want to check that, and the related editor, out. Apart from that you could add the level number as data to the link. like <a data-level="3">To level three</a>

Comment: Thanks, @TimB, questjs seems very complicated to me because, as I've said, I know almost nothing about JS. Apart from that, I will create this in Google Sites so I need to be able to insert whole page as an iframe with "embed" option there.
How exactly would you go with <a data-level="3">To level three</a>? I don't understand where to insert it so it'd function properly.

Comment: As I said, QuestJS also has an editor (in another, linked repository) available. Alternatively you could try out textadventures.co.uk — there you could even upload your game. I recommend you first learn how JavaScript, and perhaps jQuery, work, because I don't know how your game is supposed to work so I can't tell you how exactly to do it.

Comment: Thanks again @TimB, I've managed to do something which could work, but there's still no option for a link to be clickable.

Comment: have a look at JavaScript querySelector and addEventListener. Give the link an id or class. Make a querySelector for that class or ID. Then add event listener for click, select the data for which level to move to, and tada. You need to remove the level link or disable it after, though.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I've managed to put together something which could work like a text adventure or a simple QA game, but there's still no option for a link to be clickable.

```
function myFunction() {
  var text;
  var answers = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  switch(answers) {
    case "answer1":
    text = "THAT IS THE CORRECT ANSWER. HERE IS YOUR LINK: https://www.link-which-should-be-clickable.com";
    break;

    case "answer2":
    location="https://www.link-which-should-be-clickable.com";
    break;

    case "answer3":    
    txt.link("https://www.link-which-should-be-clickable.com")
    break;

    default:
    text = "THAT IS NOT THE CORRECT ANSWER";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

"answer1" just writes text, "answer2" redirects to that page, "answer3" doesn't do anything. Is there really no way of making a link clickable in this form?